# How do I retrieve an item from a queue on a delay?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, scheduling

My goal is to delete messages a variable number of seconds after receiving them via events in Python.
An example timeline where there is a 5 seconds delay is as follows:

```
0: Message "foo" received
3: Message "bar" received
5: Message "foo" deleted
8: Message "bar" deleted
```

My initial idea is to put the messages in a `PriorityQueue` where their priority is the absolute time at which they should be handled.
Another thread handles the deletion of these messages. On a loop, it 'peeks' the first object and sleeps until it is time to delete the message:

```
import threading
import time
from queue import PriorityQueue

class Scheduler:

    def __init__(self):
        self.deletion_queue = PriorityQueue()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            handle_moment, msg = self.deletion_queue.get(block=True)
            if time.time() >= handle_moment:
                print(f'At {int(time.time() - start_time)}, we delete {msg}')
            else:
                self.deletion_queue.put((handle_moment, msg))
                time.sleep(handle_moment - time.time())


scheduler = Scheduler()
threading.Thread(target=scheduler.run).start()

start_time = time.time()
print(f'Message foo received at {int(time.time() - start_time)}')
scheduler.deletion_queue.put((time.time() + 5, "foo"))
time.sleep(3)
print(f'Message bar received at {int(time.time() - start_time)}')
scheduler.deletion_queue.put((time.time() + 5, "bar"))
```

This code has two problems:

1. `PriorityQueue` has no implementation of `peek()`. As a result, we have to retrieve and put the element in the Queue again later. From what I've seen, people recommend using a `Deque`, but there is no `PriorityDeque` that combines the two.
2. This only works as long as the delay given to the objects is constant. Else, objects with a delay lower than the remaining sleeping time of the scheduling thread will be deleted late.

Ideally, I would see code similar to this, or possibly an even more elegant solution that I haven't thought of:

```
deletion_queue = DelayedQueue()
deletion_queue.put(item, delay)

# This only reveals an item (like a FifoQueue) after the delay has expired for the item.
deletion_queue.get(block=True)
```

Comment: Have you looked at `heapq`?

Comment: @quamrana I hadn't until now. It looks like it could solve the two issues I outlined, but I don't think it comes with a convenient `get()` function that blocks until there are elements of which the delay expired.